# the first line output nothing in powershell

Tags: powershell

i try output parameter value in PowerShell, but it output nothing for the first time.

i have to try multiple times and it always succeeds after the first output.
does anyone know the problem?

here is the code `test.ps1`:

```
Get-Content D:/Config.txt | Foreach-Object{    
$var = $_.Split('=')    
New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
}
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor black 
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor green 
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor blue
```

Config.txt

```
DeskTopPath=D:\Users\Test\Desktop
```

my output

```
D:\Users\Test\Desktop
D:\Users\Test\Desktop
```

my PowerShell version: 5.1.14393.3471

Comment: I think a delay is needed. If you add a sleep timer for 200 ms before the first `write-host`, it’ll probably work.

Comment: `write-host` writes to the console immediately. It doesn’t wait for or care about what the pipeline is processing. It is simply executing too fast before your variable is created. You either need to add a sleep or delay or don’t use `write-host`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on PS 5.1.18362.752. Works as intended. Did you save the code in a .ps1 file or copypasted it into a psh prompt?

Comment: yes, the code is saved as `test.ps1`; i also try `write-host` and have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Host` writes to the console immediately. It doesn’t wait for or care about what the pipeline is processing. It is simply executing too fast before your variable is created. You either need to add a sleep or delay or don’t use `Write-Host`.

```
Get-Content D:/Config.txt | Foreach-Object{    
$var = $_.Split('=')    
New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
}
Start-Sleep -m 200
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor black 
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor green 
Write-Host $DeskTopPath -BackgroundColor blue
```

This isn't reproducible for everyone because of the number of variables involved in running PowerShell code. It will have to be trial and error.

Comment: i try the delay but the first `Write-Host` output is null. I also delay longer to 800, it's not changed the result. thanks for your response!